# Macro Development Assistance please

Tags: excel, vba

So the below code is pretty self explantory, but for the avoidance of doubt this is what it does

If i press enter on any cell in Col X it then moves me down to the next row starting in Col E. Much like pressing enter in MS word and starting a new line for example.

However when the sheet is protected to prevent the deletion of formulas it moves to Col C and not Col E. I need to try to get this to work in protected mode as it does in unprotected mode, this is the code me and a colleague came up with but its not worked. Please note we are novices when it comes to excel so please reply with this in mind.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123456"
  If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Column > 24 Then Cells(Target.Row + 1, "E").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123456"
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that your `Exit Sub` will leave your sheet unprotected when `Target.CountLarge > 1` since you are skipping the password protection at the end. You may want to act on the negative there so you don't have to do an early exit and miss things like protecting the worksheet again

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, although a bit slow. That is because you don't need to unprotect/protect the worksheet to select. You can leave out the Protect and Unprotect statements. I tested in Office 2013, W10, all works. Also the code does not give any reason why it would go to column C. Maybe you need to be more specific to when that happens. Another thing: note that the code is not only called on 'pressing enter', but any selection change (cursor keys, clicks), but I suppose that is exactly what you want to protect the formulas past column X.

Answer (score 0):

*When you select a cell you trigger your macro, and then when your macro selects another cell, you re-trigger your macro, and then when your macro selects......*

You are going into a infinite loop causing your instance of Excel to crash. Disable `Events` before taking any actions that would recall your macro like so:

---

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Select cell here
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: How would the overall code look per say? Can you provide a full working example?

Comment: You just drop your select line in there. Pretty straight forward

Comment: Or just add these lines I shared as your first line of code and last line of code... (inside the sub/end sub of course)

Comment: So i edited your answer with the solution is this correct?

Comment: Just test it @LordSnow - you can find out on your end.

Comment: That repsonse was as helpful as a chocolate fire guard, i asked if the edited solution i provided was correct in the way you advised to create it. Do simple questions baffle you? Prick.

Comment: Minimal effort is expected on your end. In the time it took you to make that edit here you could have just as easily tested it yourself rather asking the people volunteering their time to your problem to test it for you.